# How to use authentification on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm looking for a good example, documentation or starting point for the following scenario.

1. My own Google App (Java Servlet) running within Google App Engine
2. SSL activated for this app
3. A mobile Android app talking to my Google App
4. OAuth or other?

My problem is step 4. Somehow I want to make sure that only my Android app is allowed to talk to my Google App and depending on the user on the mobile device I have to restrict the privileges.

But I couldn't find a "very simple" "easy to start" documentation. Would be glad if someone gives me a hint. A very short example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start for this is the [Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) documentation. This is the best way to implement an API for an Android application, because it auto-generates the serialization/deserialization for you as well as the Android client library code necessary to make the requests. You'll notice as you look through the documentation that you can specify a "User" object as a parameter, which will automatically be injected with the logged-in user. Furthermore, the "clientIds" and "audiences" allow you to restrict the API to applications which you authorize.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good starting point. I will dig into it.

Comment: I would probably disagree that Cloud Endpoints is "the best way". I had so many issues with it, I've stopped using it, and now use Restlet.org.

Comment: Can you provide a good step-by-step documentation how to use Restlet with Google App Engine? The docu that I found was not really good though.

Comment: This is obviously a matter of opinion, but based on the documentation, I would have to strongly disagree with @pinoyyid's assessment. It looks like the Restlet API requires you to manually parse the content of the request, perform authentication, and manually serialize the responses -- all of which endpoints automates. In any event, they do have an "edition" (in the downloads section) targetted for running on Google App Engine.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the documentation to form an opinion. Try working with GCE for a while and then decide. The GCE authentication doesn't work the way you expect it to. Also "Restlet API requires you to manually parse the content of the request...and manually serialize the responses " is very wrong.

Comment: @mathias. I agree the documentation isn't great. You need to implement a dispatcher class which binds each URL pattern to a controller. Then implement a controller with a method for each of the http verbs. The method will be passed an instantiated model object, formed **automatically** by parsing the JSON. NB. This is all about building a full public REST API. It may well be that a simple servlet will do the job for you. Also, to be fair to GCE, if you want to prototype something, it's very quick to try once you get through the jar maze. It may well meet your needs if they are simple enough.